# Populate multiple variables of text based on example string in python

Tags: python, regex, date, variables, yaml

I'm trying to make a yml config file that lets a user set an example of how a filename is formatted and have the program interpret it, so it's future-proofed if the naming scheme of the file is updated in the future.

for example:

config.yml

```
log_name_scheme: statYYYYMM.log
```

then use python to interpret where to place the 4 digit year and month. I already have code that determines the month and year, and it all works when the filename prefix and suffix are hardcoded, But I want to account for any contingency, if the prefix or suffix change, if month and day are flipped, or even if other characters are inserted in-between. I also have to account for a mode where I read 12 of these files, and I'm thinking of adding a custom range function where I specify a start and end date and generate stats from that.

I'm not going to go so far as to future-proof the month being turned from an integer into a word, unless that's easy to account for.

I'm assuming I'd do this with Regex, but in doing some searching I haven't found anything similar to work off of and figure it out.

Comment: add fields to your template string: `${year}`, easy to find and replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rioV8 gave me the lead I needed:

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#template-strings

I thought I wouldn't be able to include that sort of stuff in the yml file since i'm safe-loading it, but it worked

config.yml

```
 log_name_scheme: stat$year$month.log
```

and in my python:

```
logfile = Template(config["log_name_scheme"])
print(logfile.substitute(year=args.year.strftime("%Y"), month=args.month.strftime("%m")))
```

thanks for the quick reply!